# Basic and extended Permissions - friends list

Tags: facebook, permissions

I viewed the list of basic info permissions:

> id
>   name
>   first_name
>   last_name
>   link
>   username
>   gender
>   locale

And at the **extended** there is this permission:

> read_friendlists

part of the description of this permissions I see this:

> "All user's friends are provided as part of basic data..."

So my question is: Is the users friends list part of the basic info permissions?

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is: Is the users friends list is or is not part of the basic info permissions?

A list of the user’s friends is part of basic permissions – and you can read them via `/userid/friends`

But “Friendlists” are something different – `/userid/friendlists` gives you the *lists* that the user’s friends are sorted into – some of them automatically created by Facebook, some possibly created by the user themselves. Those lists can have different types: close_friends, acquaintances, restricted,user_created, education, work, current_city or family.

And to read those *friendlists*, you need `read_friendlists` permission (the clue’s already in the name here).

Should all be quite obvious, if one takes a minute of time to look up the description of these user connections in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is now outdated, and that you may not look at the User's Friend List. This is unfortunate as I have been working on a project that was based off that idea.