# Why my Facebook app asks asks if I'd like to access their friend list?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing a Facebook application which only requires access to their basic user information and e-mail address. In the scope I specify the e-mail and my URL like so:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/&state=d8c7767e8aa5470a44ec50c2737e2d8a&display=popup&scope=email

However, when I open that URL, Facebook asks:

> *Example App* would like to access your public profile, **friend list** and
>   email address.

I have not specified the friend list permission, nor do I want it.

Comment: Do you have other specific settings in your Facebook App?

Comment: I don't believe I've set any of those settings. I've taken a look through the app on Facebook, but I'm unable to find anything additional that I've added.

Comment: See this bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/528423520559440

Answer (score 3):

The **friend list** is part of **basic permissions**.

You can read the list of friends via `/userid/friends` and this list is different than the extended permission `read_friendlists`, which are the list you created and added your friends to those (e.g. University, StackOverflow, my company...).

That's why Facebook automatically ask for it even if you do not specify those extra permissions in your Facebook App settings or in your query ([scope](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) query string).

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13358525) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14077513).

Comment: Thank you! It just seemed very worrying when it was asking for "friend list" as I assumed that was the same as the extended permission for the list. Perhaps Facebook should make a greater distinction between the two.

Comment: True, this is confusing and only the last "s" in permissions can differentiate them. The good thing is that your code works and you have no configuration problem.